# Cannot call function (properly) in C++

Tags: c++, dll, immunity-debugger, dll-injection

I am developing a DLL for the purpose of injecting it into a running process for a game. I've found the memory addresses to some key functions(via Immunity Debugger) and I am trying to call those functions from within' my injected DLL.

So far whenever I inject my DLL and press the hotkey combination of ALT+T, the game client stops responding and crashes. At one particular instance it showed a debug error saying: "The process was not able to resume execution because the ESP value was changed", or something similar.

Do I have to alter the ESP value before and after I call the process function from within' my DLL? If so, how would I do this properly.

Here is the source code of my DLL:

```
// Warband_Chat.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h> // Include the functions we are going to use like Sleep and hInstance etc...
#include <fstream> // Allows us to work with files on the hard drive.
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 300 // Maximum chat message size: 300 characters.
#define ThreadMake(x) CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&x,NULL,NULL,NULL); // Makes creating threads easy, it just requires 1 parameter(the function).
using namespace std;

// Define process(Warband) function based on its parameters and its location in memory.
typedef void(__cdecl* ChatFunc)(char*);
ChatFunc Chat = (ChatFunc)0x00450C60;


wchar_t *convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
/* Converts a char array to a LCPWSTR string. */
{
    wchar_t* wString=new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
}


int getkey(char x) // A function I made to get 1 key and automatically check ALT(vk_menu,0x12)
{
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU)&0x8000 && GetAsyncKeyState(x)&0x8000)//Check if we are pressing ALT and what ever is inside x
    {
        return 1; // if we are then return true.
    }
    return 0; // If the condition is not met then return false
}


void main() // the main function
{
    while(1) // the main loop
    {
        if(getkey('T')) // If we are pressing ALT + T then do
        {
                        ifstream file("chat.txt");
                        if (!file.is_open())
                        {
                                MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to open chat.txt. Make sure its on your root Mount & Blade: Warband folder.", L"Failed", MB_OK);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                                file.getline(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-1);
                                Chat(buffer); // Call chat function
                                LPCWSTR newbuffer = convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(buffer);
                                MessageBox(NULL, newbuffer, L"Success", MB_OK); // Post a message if we injected.
                                // the L before the messages is just to tell MSVS that those are LPCTSTR characters.
                        }
                        file.close();
            Sleep(20); // Sleep so we don't lag
        }
                Sleep(20); // no lag.
    }
}


extern "C" // DLL Hook
{
    __declspec(dllexport) BOOL __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD reason,LPVOID lpv)
    {
        if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        {
            DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hInst);
            ThreadMake(main); // Creates a new thread on the process.
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure the function you're calling is not subject to ASLR?

Comment: Not the problem you want to hear about, but your `main` function should be `LRESULT` instead of `void` and should have return statement.

Answer (score 2):

> At one particular instance it showed a debug error saying: "The
>   process was not able to resume execution because the ESP value was
>   changed", or something similar.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> typedef void(__cdecl* ChatFunc)(char*);
> ChatFunc Chat = (ChatFunc)0x00450C60;
> ```

It sounds like the function at `0x00450C60` is not a `__cdecl` function and/or it doesn't take exactly one function argument. Re-analyze the disassembly of that function and fix your prototype.

Comment: How would I determine what type of function that is via Olly Debugger?

Comment: You can determine the function's calling convention by looking at its assembly code. You can check out http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions for reference.